# JSON using a key - value as variable

Tags: python, json

i'm defining a JSON file as configuration file for a Python program. The JSON file is created by hand and then i will use Python to read the JSON and extract the data.
My point is to the value of a key multiple times. An example:

```
{
 "seed" : 7,
 "algo1": {
 "random_state": {seed} 
 },
 "algo2": {
 "random_state": {seed} 
 }
}
```

The idea is to use the value defined in the seed key (7 in this example) as value of other keys. Can i use this approach? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Create a variable seed = 7, and do "seed" : seed?

Comment: I think that is not possible to define a variable inside a json file

Comment: I am not sure exactly I understand your question, so you have the value here in a JSON you have read, where now you have stored the variable for the random_state for algo1 and 2, your "{seed}" is actually just a random value you put by hand. What next?

Comment: Since if I have a lot of random_state parameter, probably i could forgot some of them. The idea is to reduce this possible error.

Comment: I still just don't understand what you are trying to do, can you try to reword it? @Ivan

Comment: I want to use the value defined in the key seed in other keys (eg random_state). The idea is to use the seed key as a variable inside a json file created by hand. In this way, i can change only the seed key to update the other keys (eg the random_state keys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many `algos` you want to have in this dict/json, you could try appending new `algos` as such:

```
cfg = with open('path_to_file/person.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)  

cfg["algo1"] = {"random state": cfg["seed"]}

cfg["algo2"] = {"random state": cfg["seed"]}
```

Comment: Sorry, probably my question is not clear. The JSON file is not generated by a Python program, i create the JSON file by hand and then i use python to read the JSON. I add this detail in the question.

Comment: @Ivan Would it still not work even if you read the json from file? And if you create the file by hand no less, why not just write/copy the seed where you want it to be?

Comment: Since if I have a lot of random_state parameter, probably i could forgot some of them. The idea is to reduce this possible error.